# How to make a regex compatible with a normal string and a string starts with a newline

Tags: python, regex

problematic code:

```
out, err = shellcmd.run_get_out(shell_cmd, login_shell=True)
p = re.compile('^' + module + '/(.*)$')
m = p.match(out)
if m:
    return m.group(1)
return None
```

It get the output from some shell command and do a regular expression match. For example: out is 'rvct/4.1_0894\n' and module is 'rvct', it returns '4.1_0894'
But on some system, the shell command output starts with a new line, the out will be '\nrvct/4.1_0894\n', I have to make this change

```
p = re.compile('^\n' + module + '/(.*)$')
```

to make it work

Can I have a regex working on both situations? I have tried

```
p = re.compile('^' + module + '/(.*)$', re.MULTILINE)
```

It seems not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can strip newlines from the output first, using `out.strip()`.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could skip any number of leading newlines with a star:

```
p = re.compile('^\n*' + module + '/(.*)$')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the newline optional in your pattern:

```
p = re.compile('^\n?' + module + '/(.*)$')
```

`?` is here a quantifier meaning 0 or 1

See [repeating things in the regex chapter on docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#repeating-things)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
p = re.compile('^' + "nacho" + '/(.*)$', re.DOTALL)
```

i.e.:

```
>>> re.findall("(.*)$", myvar, re.DOTALL)
['dfasd\nasdf\nadsfasdgasdgadfga\ndfasdf\nga\ndf\nga\n\n\n', '']
```

Your problems is that the '.' don't match newlines if you don't tell it to do it.